# h2 console not being found in browser while running springboot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, server, h2

Im trying to get the h2 console in my browser while my my Springboot application.

> Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for
> /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Sun Apr 24 00:44:22 IST 2022 There was an unexpected error (type=Not
> Found, status=404).

This is my application.properties file

```
spring.h2.console.enable=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:memDb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
```

I have tried both

```
http://localhost:8080/h2/
```

and

```
http://localhost:8080/h2-console/
```

This is the log I get every time I enter either of those 2 URLs in the browser

```
2022-04-24 00:53:27.718  INFO 6060 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-04-24 00:53:27.719  INFO 6060 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-04-24 00:53:27.720  INFO 6060 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
```

Also in my problems terminal of my project ide
It says this for each line in my application.properties

```
Unused property:1
Unused property:2
Unused property:4
Unused property:5
Unused property:6
Unused property:7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing "d" - enabled

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```